# What part of speech is "based on"

Tags: commas, parts-of-speech

Google Flights explains its reasoning for 'best' flights with the following:

> We chose options that give you the best trade-off between price and convenience, **based on** factors such as duration, number of stops, and airport changes during layovers.
>
> **To select these results**, Google Flights compared offers from over 300 travel partners, including airlines, online travel agencies, and aggregators. Results may not reflect all available offers.
>
> Google may be compensated by some of these travel partners, but this doesn't affect the ranking of results.

I'm curious about the first and second sentences. How is the "**..., based on...**" justified in grammatical terms? The second sentence begins with "**To select these results, ...**" That also seems off.

Comment: It is not a part of speech. It is a verb and a preposition.

Comment: @Lambie I think that it's not so simple. Cambridge Dictionary states that "based" it's an adjective and in that sentence it is describing a characteristic of the noun "options".

Comment: @RubioRic It is a past participle adverbial phrase describing how "we chose options".

Answer (score 1):

It's an adverb (more specifically past participle adverbial phrase as @Lambie says) modifying either "chose" or "give."  [Reference](https://www.dictionary.com/e/whats-an-adverbial-phrase/).

It can answering "how?" to either of the questions "We chose X" or "options that give you the best..."

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. "Based on", "given", "according to", and "regarding" are examples of expressions derived from a verb that are evolving into grammatical items.

For example:

- "Given" used as a connective has no "giver" and no active verb paraphrase:

  - **Given** the bad weather, I would rather stay inside. (nothing is "giving" bad weather)
- "Based on" has a similar meaning to "given", but does allow internal modification—it is not *completely* frozen:

  - **Based *only* on** the information you provided, ...

The dirty secret about grammar is that descriptive categories are imperfect/do not tell the whole story as certain words and expressions behave in grammatically idiosyncratic ways.

Answer (score 0):

"To select these results" is an adverbial purpose clause. It can be paraphrased as "In order to select these results".